# Extra badges for offering bounty

Tags: discussion, badges, bounties

This question: [Delinking bounties from privileges - spent bountry rep should regenerate over time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116733/delinking-bounties-from-privileges-spent-bountry-rep-should-regenerate-over-ti) in proximity to [my own badge request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116735/158428) made me think of a possible alternative.

I agree with the down-voters of the first question that this is not a good plan for the site.  However, better badges for offering a bounty might be useful, without breaking the system.

I propose a silver and gold badge, each based on total bounty offered **and** percentage of reputation offered as bounty.

For example, one might get a silver badge for offering 500 *total* bounty **and** total bounty amounts to 25% of reputation at the time of offering the bounty.  Gold could be perhaps 2000 **and** 25%.

This should serve to reward users with at least moderate reputation who are generous with their bounties, without being devalued as automatic badges for every high-rep user.

Comment: What about the people who ask a lot of questions which get answered right away? A lot of users never really have the need to use bounties. I think the bounty badges should remain as bronze "teach me how to do this" badges.

Comment: @animuson pardon me, but I don't understand your point.  The first two sentences appear logically unrelated to the third.

Answer (score 2):

Badges should encourage beneficial behavior.

There are already 4 badges for the use of bounties:

- Two for offering and awarding a bounty on your own question.
- Two for offering and awarding a bounty on someone else's question.

To earn these 4 badges, you have to learn how to offer and award bounties (which seems to be the purpose of most bronze badges).

I do **not** think that badges for more bounties also encourage beneficial behavior nor that having those badges is really fair.

- Badges should reward you for doing something good.

  Bounties are used to attract more attention to a specific question or to reward a single user for his answer. In both cases, the bounty does not benefit the entire community.
- Offering bounties already gives you a reward, and it's more important than any badge you could get: You attract more attention to your question, which will probably result in an answer.
- Badge `X` for `N` reputation is a simple trade-off.

  Users with high reputation could just "buy" the badges.

Comment: I thought that offering a bounty *was* beneficial behavior.  As you just wrote, the existing badges are little more than a "I know how to use feature X" reward.  I think that offering a significant bounty *beneficially* rewards others for participating, and the reputation you use has to come from some presumably *beneficial* action on the site. Surely offering a bounty for someone else's question is a beneficial behavior if it generates good answers to a hard question.  You say that users with high reputation could "buy" the badges, but how many would give up 25% of their reputation to do so?

Comment: I have to admit that I did not read the `25 %` part. But I doubt that it will benefit anybody if someone throws away a quarter of their reputation for bounties. I admit that offering bounties on other users' questions might result in more benefits to the site than to the user itself, but I don't think that offering bounties on your own questions should be further rewarded.

Comment: Do you think that any variation of the concept has merit, or are you wholesale against it?

Comment: I'd welcome the variation `silver badge for awarding a total of X bounty points on other users' questions`. I don't think the percentage idea is a good one and I think this is not enough for a gold badge.

Comment: Thank you.  As you can see I didn't mark this question [tag:feature-request] because I didn't give it much thought.  It appears the idea is neither popular nor hated and should be left to slip into obscurity.  I could support the silver badge you propose, if you care to make it a new question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I will if I can come up with the details.